# Create a new package from an existing installed python package

Tags: python

I made many changes to a library installed with pip (library not maintained anymore) and I want to create a new package that I can use for my own projects without each time to install the library using pip and then change the files I modified.

Is there a way?

Comment: Is the source code for that library in a public repository (e.g., github)? Does it have a permissive license for modification/re-use/distribution?

Comment: If it's in a public Git repo, you could [fork that repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo), make your changes, and [upload it to PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-the-distribution-archives) with a new package name.

Comment: Or, you could just copy all the code into your project as a subpackage and then use it within your project as you would any other subpackage within it (you'd need to make sure your build system contains all the requirements of that original library).

Comment: If you are welling to take over maintenance and it's uploaded on github, you might also be able to contact the original author/current (inactive) maintainer and take over project.